# Facebook - Move ap from Pages to profile page?

Tags: facebook

How do I move my ap from Pages to profile page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about installing an app in an user profile page - this feature has been removed from facebook long time ago

if you want to install it on a fan page -

1. On a fan page at http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php, if the page aleady exist - make sure you administrate it
2. make sure you filled the "Page Tab" setting of your application
3. go to this link (change the APP_ID to your application's id) and choose the page you want to install your app on from the list:
   http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_ID&pages
   (the id of your application can be found in the developers.facebook.com/apps site

Comment: I basically have a normal facebook account. and have created my own canvas design that I want to put into my normal facebook account. It only lets me add canvas to "pages" then within pages I select my app/canvas. I want mine like this example: http://www.facebook.com/victoriassecret

Comment: changed my answer to fit your request

Comment: ah so I guess scrap the normal facebook page and just use it as an adim user. Then use a fan page as my main ? guess thats possible

Comment: Dam it looks like a fan page works very differently "you can’t friend someone the way you can from your profile" ? hmmm

Comment: a fan page **is** different than user profile, and has very different purposes.

Comment: yea, think I should of done my research :( ... thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, you cannot add an application to your profile page. This is not like myspace where you can insert apps onto your profile view for others to see. If that is what you meant. Your question is a little vague. I think you have to access your Apps through the tabs to the left of your home page.

Comment: This company can do it: http://www.facebook.com/victoriassecret

Comment: Right, so you can ONLY use this feature on Pages. Not Facebook User Profiles.
EDIT: And the use of the word ap for the image banner is a little misleading.

Comment: but when you look at victoriassecret facebook page it loads up a fancy canvas ?. I have designed a canvas but not sure how I get it into my normal facebook profile for people to see when they look me up

Comment: Again, you cannot put the canvas on a normal Facebook account as far as I have ever seen. Victorias Secret is a Page Profile, not a regular user profile. There are differences in the two types.

Comment: Dam it looks like a fan page works very differently "you can’t friend someone the way you can from your profile" ? hmmm

Comment: Right, they basically have to look for you, you cannot look for them as far as I know. The best you can do is post a link in your Normal Facebook Account for your friends to go Follow your Fan Page. Good Luck.